# 出来るなら関係代数、無理ならSQLの実行計画を表示できるフリーのソフトはありますか

Tags: json, sql, xml

例えばSQL Management Studio,黒猫 SQL StudioでSQLの実行計画を表示することが出来ます。
調べた限りではSQL Management Studioでは.sqlplanでxmlファイルを書くことにより実行計画の情報をグラフィカルに表示できます。
これを汎用的にブラウザで表示したいので3d.jsなど関係代数の実行計画を表示するのに最も向いているフリー表示用ライブラリ、ソフトはありませんか？
SQL Management Studioでは表現力に限界を感じています。例えばネストしたSQLを表示することができません。
実行計画はxml,jsonなどで自力で用意しておいてそれを表示させるのが可能な方法は何かないでしょうか？

Comment: SQLの実行計画に限定したコメントです。質問された方の趣旨とちがうかもしれないので、「回答」ではなく「コメント」を使用しています。

実行計画を調べるため、Oracleの`explain for`を使ったことがあります。ちょっと調べてみましたが、MySQL(これもOracleか)やPostgreSQLにも類似ツールがあるようです。